# R: vosonSML issue

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, filter

I'm trying to use the R package vosonSML (https://github.com/vosonlab/vosonSML?tab=readme-ov-file), and when trying to run the function:

```
pages <-
  tibble::tibble(page = c("https://www.lslr-collaborative.org/about-us.html",
                      "https://www.epa.gov/dwcapacity/voluntary-school-and-child-care-lead-testing-and-reduction-state-grant-program-contacts",
                      "https://www.edf.org/health/recognizing-efforts-replace-lead-service-lines"
                       ),
             type = rep("ext", 3), 
             max_depth = rep(2, 3))

data <- Authenticate("web") %>% Collect(pages, verbose=TRUE)
```

for certain urls I get this error:

```
Error in `dplyr::filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `.data$parse$domain != init_url_dets$domain`.
Caused by error in `.data$parse`:
! Column `parse` not found in `.data`.
```

Has anyone else run into this issue or have any ideas for how to fix it?

I can skip over problematic websites with:

```
tryCatch({
   
    data <- Authenticate("web") %>% Collect(pages, verbose=TRUE)
    
    # If successful, add the data to the list
    web_links[[url]] <- data
    
  }, error = function(e) {
    # If an error occurs, skip this URL and print a message
    print(paste("Error processing URL:", url))
  })
```

However, I don't understand why there are issues with certain sites.